# android backslash key press simulation

Tags: android, android-edittext, simulation, keypress

I need to simulate backslash key press when Y press on a button. in onClick method for that button I have the code:

```
KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACKSLASH);
editText.onKeyUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACKSLASH, event);
```

but this doesn't works. Can you give me an idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I have a dialpad with buttons for digits and when I want to delete, I must delete digit before cursor and when I press a button wo write a digit I must add digit after cursor and this is a lot of code to write so I thought it would much easier to use the default behaviour

Comment: Don't feel like there's much code, so you'd better implement the behaviour yourself. Many phones have no hardware keyboards and no backspace key, so this is not a good solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```